# Copying of data of one categorical variable into another variable

Tags: r

This is the code

```
a <- c("a","b","c")
a <- factor(a)
d <- c()
for(i in 1:3)
  {
   d[i] <- a[i]
  }
print(d)
```

the output should be same  a
but the output is 1 2 3

Comment: Try `c(a[1])` on your console. `factors` are integers under the hood.

Comment: You can just say `d <- a` If you want to copy one variable into another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` needs to be a factor as well, and needs to have compatible levels:

```
a <- c("a","b","c")
a <- factor(a)
d <- factor(c(),levels=levels(a))
for(i in 1:3)
{
  d[i] <- a[i]
}
print(d)
# [1] a b c
# Levels: a b c
```

In your code the factor was coerced to integer

Comment: as I understand OP wanted to understand what's going on, not just copy a variable, I assume his real code is a bit different